# Laravel data bind on vue tamplate

Tags: vue.js, laravel-5, data-binding

hello i am try to bind user_name to .vue from this object in laravel::

```
{ "order": [ { "id": 87, "user_id": "2", "user_name": "Mohamed Hassan", "table": 20, "total": 224, "status": 1, "delivered": 0, "paied": 0, "created_at": "2019-09-14 15:04:40", "updated_at": "2019-09-14 15:04:40" } ] }
```

and this object get from:

```
 {{order.data}}
```

and when iam try

```
   {{order.data['order']}}
```

get this

```
 [ { "id": 87, "user_id": "2", "user_name": "Mohamed Hassan", "table": 20, "total": 224, "status": 1, "delivered": 0, "paied": 0, "created_at": "2019-09-14 15:04:40", "updated_at": "2019-09-14 15:04:40" } ]
```

iam try:

```
 {{order.data['order']['user_name']}}
```

but return null

and this my .vue temp:

```
<li v-for="order in orders">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3"><div class="notify-img">{{order.data}}</div></div>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-9 pd-l0"><a href="">Date: </a>  <a href="">{{order.created_at}}</a> <a href="" class="rIcon"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i></a>
            <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor amet consilium.</p>
            <p class="time">1 Saat önce</p>
            <hr>
            </div>

        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{order.data['order']}}` returns an array which you could access its items using indexes like :

```
  {{order.data['order'][0]['user_name']}}
```